# Observer Pattern in java, a better way?

Tags: java

The code below was taken from another SO post, I was wondering is there a better way of writing this code, because its kind of ugly to have a loop that notifies all the listener at the end of every implemented method. If this is silly forgive me, I am new to `Java`.

Note: I will be implementing more than one method in the interface, I will have 5 methods implemented:

```java
import java.util.*;

interface HelloListener {
    public void someoneSaidHello();
}


class Initiater {
    List<HelloListener> listeners = new ArrayList<HelloListener>();

    public void addListener(HelloListener toAdd) {
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!!");

        // Notify everybody that may be interested.
        for (HelloListener hl : listeners)
            hl.someoneSaidHello();
    }
}


class Responder implements HelloListener {
    @Override
    public void someoneSaidHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello there...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that's probably the simplest solution available to you.  You could have a queue where events are pushed onto them and some kind of dispatcher notifies registered listeners, but there again, you need a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I implemented the Observer pattern as a student, I made it as an abstract class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The observer pattern.
 * @author jiman 
 */
public abstract class Observed {

    private ArrayList<Observer> observers;

    public Observed() { views = new ArrayList<Observer>(); }

    public void registerObserver(Observer o) { observers.add(o); }

    public void removeObserver(Observer o) { observers.remove(o); }

    // call this method upon a mutation of the state of this object
    public void notifyObservers() { for (Observer o : observers) o.update(); }

}
```

Observers will inherit from this interface and write their own update methods.

```
public interface Observer {

    public void update();

}
```

Comment: Rationale behind Observed being abstract and not an interface: Abstract classes can implement methods and contain variables. Thus, you don't have to re-implement that code each time in your children classes ;)

Comment: I found out after the fact that this is almost exactly how Java does it.

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple methods that need to notify all the listeners the loop can be refactored out into its own method that can be called from each of the notifying methods.

For example, the source code for javax.swing.AbstractButton has a firestateChanged() method  for notifying listeners of a state change etc.

Comment: Yea I will have multiple methods implemented from the interface, can you show some code.

Comment: Are you *the* Patricia Shanahan of [So, You Need to Write a Program but Don't Know How to Start](http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/beginner.html) fame? If so, you are my hero!!! Seriously, I've recommended that article to countless lost souls, and it has helped quite a few. Thank you for that!

Comment: Yes, that's me. I'm glad to hear it is useful.

Comment: It states succinctly many techniques that are necessary to get over that first huge potential energy barrier that blocks a newbie coder just coming out of the gate. It is wonderful to see an educator of your repute here on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Two Classes exists in the JDK to help you do this.

[Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) (Interface) and [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) (Class)

A small example on how to use them:

```
  class MyView implements Observer {

    public void update(Observable obs, Object x) {
      System.out.println("update(" + obs + "," + x + ");");
    }
  }

  /** The Observable normally maintains the data */
  class MyModel extends Observable {

    public void changeSomething() {
      // Notify observers of change
      setChanged(); // THIS IS IMPORTANT DON'T FORGET IT!
      notifyObservers();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please, show some code with regards to the example with multiple interface methods ?

Comment: And many believe that they're not all that good, especially since Observable is a class not an interface and it forces whatever it is that you're observing to extend that class. Myself, I usually use a PropertyChangeSupport with PropertyChangeListeners to listen to changes in class state.